# How to cancel coroutine with blocking code

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to run some long running task in coroutine. Sometimes i need to cancel this coroutine, but after `job.cancel()` it still continues to work.

Here is some code demonstration similar to my real code:

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    val job = Job()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO + job, block =
        {
            for (i in 0..100)
            {
                Log.e("TestActivity", "Time passed = ${i * 100}")
                Thread.sleep(100)
            }

            Log.e("TestActivity", "Code after cycle")
        })

        Handler().postDelayed(
            {
                Log.e("TestActivity", "**** Trying to cancel job ****")
                job.cancel()
            }, 3000)
    }
}
```

In my logcat i get logs after cancelling job.

```
...
TestActivity: Time passed = 2300
TestActivity: Time passed = 2400
TestActivity: **** Trying to cancel job ****
TestActivity: Time passed = 2500
TestActivity: Time passed = 2600
...
TestActivity: Code after cycle
```

What is the proper way to cancel such tasks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make your coroutines cooperative with cancellation. If you make use of any suspending function from `kotlinx.coroutines` then it's already cooperative with cancellation. For example instead of `Thread.sleep` use `delay`:

```
...
for (i in 0..100)
{
    Log.e("TestActivity", "Time passed = ${i * 100}")
    delay(100)
}
...
```

When you have a heavy task and you're not calling a suspending function from `kotlinx.coroutines`, you can check its `isActive` property when necessary which will be `false` if the coroutine is cancelled:

```
...
for (i in 0..100)
{
    if(!isActive)
        break;
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. So if i have for example someLongRunningMethod() in my coroutine and it was started before job.cancel() it will run and will be finished anyway? I cant stop it?

Comment: @Bios90 After calling `job.cancel` the coroutine's `isActive` property will be `false` so you can check that property and stop the process by returning or breaking the loop or any other method you consider appropriate. The coroutine won't stop by itself, you have to make it cooperative with cancellation and you have these 2 previous approaches to achieve it.

Comment: @Bios90 Coroutines are meant to be suspended and once they suspend they automatically cancels, if they don't suspend you have to do checks to cooperate with cancellation.